Is it possible to change default trophy list language on PS4 or PS5?
I'm Pinckerman, you may remember me from my previous question: Which language will be the Japanese retail version of TBOI: Repentance?
Quick update: I purchased the Pikii's retail version of the game, which has in fact Japanese as the default language, but also English localization (luckily). My problem is that the trophy list is in Japanese, too (sadly).
Is there a way to change the default trophy language on PS4 or PS5?
It's a similar problem I had with Genshin Impact, but that was a PS4 known bug which was fixed on PS5, so I hope for a different outcome this time.

I checked on PSN Profiles and the copy I own is registered as the Japanese list, so that's why my PS4 has Japanese trophies by default.

I don't think there's a solution.

So you mean that even if your PS4 is in English, your account too, and all your games achievements in English too, if you have the Japanese version of a game, those achievements in particular are in Japanese?

@xtropicalsoothing good question. I don't know if that's the rule, but this game has a US/EU version published by Nicalis and a JP one published by Pikii, so they are essantially a different game
